# Monotonicity of cubic function in Bernstein basis

Tags: polynomials, roots, monotone-functions

Given a cubic polynomial in monomial basis, i.e. $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$, the condition for it to be monotonic on $x \in R$ is that it's derivative, $f'(x) = a_1 + 2a_2x + 3a_3x^2$, has at most one real root, which is satisfied when $a_2^2 - 3a_1a_3 \le 0$.

Also, if we require a cubic function to be monotonic on some interval $x \in [a, b]$, then this translates into a condition for its extrema to be outside this interval. So, we can find the two extrema by solving the quadratic equation $f'(x_*) = 0$ which has the roots

$$
x_*=\frac{-a_2 \pm \sqrt{a_2^2 - 3a_1a_3}}{3a_3}
$$

and the condition is for $x_* \notin [a,b]$.

Is there also a simple condition / expression on the coefficients when a cubic function is expressed in Bernstein basis, i.e.

$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^3\beta_k \left( \begin{matrix} 3 \\ k \\ \end{matrix} \right) x^k(1-x)^{3-k} \ ?
$$

Since Bernstein basis polynomials are positive on $(0, 1)$, I would expect there to be a simple condition on the coefficients for an existence of a root in that interval. Clearly if all $\beta_k > 0$, then there are no roots in the interval, but it seems to me that it is a sufficient condition but not a necessary one - is that correct? And how about the existence of exactly 1 root?

Is there an "easy" way to change between the two basis?  I suppose it is some kind of a matrix multiplication to go from one basis to another.

**Add 1**

It looks like the matrix to convert coefficients from Bernstein to monomial basis, $\mathbf{c}_m = (\mathbf{A}^T)^{-1} \mathbf{c}_B$, where

$$
(\mathbf{A})_{k,j \ge k} = \left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \\ \end{matrix} \right)^{-1} \left( \begin{matrix} j \\ k \\ \end{matrix} \right)
$$

and

$$
(\mathbf{A})_{k,j < k} = 0 
$$

which gives

$$
\left( (\mathbf{A}^T)^{-1} \right)_{j,k \le j} = (-1)^{j-k} \left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \\ \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} n-k \\ j-k \\ \end{matrix} \right)
$$

Comment: Guess that's $\,\beta_k\,$ in the last formula (not $\,\beta_0\,$). Anyway, you can express $\,a_i\,$ in terms of $\,\beta_j\,$ then substitute in the (same) condition.

Comment: Yes, it's $\beta_k$ - I now corrected it. Thank you

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your comment. I corrected the subscript. On the conditions: I would have thought that because Bernatein basis polynomials are positive on (0, 1) (or on other rescaled interval), there would be a simple condition on the signs of the coefficients (or something like that) that can be used to determine if there are roots of a polynomial function in that interval, no? Wouldn’t, for instance, all positive $\beta_k$ imply that there are no roots in the interval?

Comment: If you write a polynomial as a sum of other polynomials that are positive over an interval, then the sum is positive, of course. See also [Polynomial positive on an interval](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39292/polynomial-positive-on-an-interval) on MO for less trivial results and references. That said, I don't know that there is an equivalent of the classical results (Descartes' rule of signs, Sturm sequences etc) expressed directly in terms of the Bernstein coefficients.